# Do I need special gloves for mozzarella stretching?

Tags: cheese

I'd like to pick up some gloves for stretching mozzarella. I've seen gloves sold for just this on specialty sites like [thebeveragepeople.com](http://www.thebeveragepeople.com/product1341.html) and [thecheesemaker.com](http://www.thecheesemaker.com/products/Heavy-Duty-Food-Grade-Gloves.html), but I can't tell if they're just a generic product sold as something specific. Is there something generic that will work equally well for (1) hot temperatures and is (2) food safe? I'd like to be able to buy it on Amazon in particular.

Comment: Hi! Your question is a very interesting one. Being a Q&A site, we prefer all "titles" to contain a real question and not just a topic, so I edited it for you.

Comment: @rumtscho : I thought his title was fine ... sometimes it's better when the title isn't a question (like when the title question isn't the same as the body question).

Comment: @Joe It's a networkwide policy to make titles be phrased as questions. In this case, the old one was too unspecific. What does he want to know about mozzarella gloves? It's possible that I misunderstood the body and chose a title which doesn't sum up the problem well, in which case we should try to find a better question-title.

Comment: @joe OK, I have an apology: After researching, I saw that having titles worded as questions is a proposal which has been discussed, but never made into binding policy. The important part is to write meaningful, nonambiguous titles. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/writing-a-good-title for guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement for specific gloves so far as I know. Gloves themselves aren't actually even necessary. They do however keep your hands clean, and they keep any nasties that could be on your hands or arms out of the cheese. When I make mozz for my family I usually just use my clean bare hands. If I was making to sell I'd most likely use food service gloves with a little butter on them to prevent sticking during stretching, similar to when you're pulling taffy.

Comment: The main reason why I'm looking for gloves is due to discomfort from the hot mozzarella stretching. I've tried in the past and struggled with the hot temperatures on my hands. I've ended up with poor results, which I think is because I'm unable to stretch the cheese until it has cooled down a bit.

What are "food service gloves"? I imagine plain latex gloves might melt. Would rubber gloves work? (are there even food safe rubber gloves?) I'd like something reusable.

Comment: We usually use nitrile gloves because we have them on hand (they're basically hypoallergenic latex gloves). They don't provide any protection from heat though. I get your concerns though - it can be a hot for the hands. Usually I just suffer through it until it's done (it shouldn't be THAT hot and should cool quickly). You could always try layering them - get some work gloves from a car store and then latex or nitrile gloves a size or 2 larger than usual and put them over the work gloves. You'll lose some deftness but it should cut down on the heat.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why Beverage People and Cheesemaking.com recommend medium neoprene gloves is that they do protect you from the heat for a short time (as in, less than a minute), while still allowing you to get a fairly good grip on the cheese.  The neoprene gloves which you link to are fairly standard; search on "neoprene gloves" on Amazon and you'll be presented with lots of options.

However, these will still be somewhat clumsy compared to just using latex or nitrile gloves or your bare hands so if you can stand the heat, you shouldn't use the gloves.