# Gloves for newbies pulling sugar?

Tags: equipment, sugar

I have an upcoming project which is going to involve pulled sugar.

Everything I've read on the project suggests that I'm going to end up blisters or at the very least first degree burns (similar to sunburn) until I've built up some callouses.

Are there any heat-resistant gloves that are good for pulled sugar work?  I'm okay with some loss of control -- I'm only making a few arches, nothing really of fine detail.

If not, at the very least, are there materials that I should favor or avoid in this sort of work?

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/49719/67

Comment: Related to the blisters: Those are actually not from the heat, but from the friction of the sugar sticking/pulling on the skin. Just wearing any gloves at all will help with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preference for sugar work is to either use a pair of rubber-coated cotton gloves like this: [image: coated work gloves]

or to use basic cotton gloves and put latex or nitrile disposable gloves over them.

Comment: Basic cotton gloves with latex gloves over them worked ... however, the temperature at which the sugar still stuck to the gloves was lower than when it was sticking to the silpat ... so when I thought it was okay to pick up the sugar, it stuck to the gloves.  I had to wait a couple more minutes before it was okay to start pulling.  (which gave me time to change the gloves, etc.)

Comment: Ahh, I usually oil my gloves very lightly before I start. That tends to eliminate the sticking.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I just use 3 layers of food preparation latex gloves. It's far from 100% heat resistance but you can still feel what you are doing and be protected enough not to blister and cry. Cheapest option to as a box of 100 latex gloves is in the £3 region.

Also the same goes for trying to pull fresh out the oven pork or beef.

Comment: Hmm ... as a thought ... a layer of thin cotton gloves in there might trap more air to improve the insulation.  (not sure if latex / cotton / latex or or cotton / latex / latex  would be better ... or even cotton / latex / cotton / latex )

Answer (score 0):

I just bought a pair of silicone BBQ gloves on AMZN that might work well for your application.  It would be hard to do fine work with them on, but they do seem fairly flexible, considering.

Comment: Since there are probably dozens of different gloves and you're recommending a specific type, you might at least include an image of the type of glove you're recommending.

Comment: Looking at Amazon, there seem to be at least two classes of 'silicone barbeque gloves' ... there are ones that look to be cloth based & dipped (with a resulting smooth surface), and ones that look to be molded (have a texture ... most seem to have heart-shaped bumps).  There are also a few that look to be cloth but with silicone dots or bars on them (I'm thinking to avoid those).  Which type is it that you're recommending?